# At what point was the Master written out of "The Talons of Weng-Chiang"?

Tags: doctor-who, behind-the-scenes

The final six-episode story of *Doctor Who* season fourteen was "[The Talons of Weng-Chiang](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Talons_of_Weng-Chiang_(TV_story))."  Although the villains initially appear to be members of a Chinese tong group operating in nineteenth-century London, in the last two episode, it is revealed that the character the Chinese assassins are worshipping as the god Weng-Chiang is actually Magnus Greel, a war criminal from fifty-first century Australia.  Greel had traveled back to the nineteenth century using a time cabinet, but the temporal journey damaged his cell structure and left him in need of stolen life essences to prolong his existence.

The presence of an evil time-traveling human always struck me as a very odd feature of this story.  When I found out that the villain was originally intended to be the Master (who had already been seen in decayed form earlier in the season, in "The Deadly Assassin"), things seemed to make a lot more sense.  What I have not found any information about is at what stage in the script preparation the Master was removed.  So when was Greel introduced to the story to replaced the Master?

Comment: ["*The true identity of Weng-Chiang was supposed to be the desiccated, decomposing Master; there are several story elements still left over from this original plan in fact, such as the time cabinet and Magnus Greel's plan to restore himself through the life energy of others. Robert Holmes and Phillip Hinchcliffe decided not to reuse the Master, though, due to the fact that it hadn't even been a full season since his last appearance.*"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Trivia/DoctorWhoS14E6TheTalonsOfWengChiang) But you want to know specifically *when* and not just how or why?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I mean, at what stage of the creative process.  Obviously, other information about how the change was made would be great too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did it strike you as an odd feature? There had already been a time-travelling villain who wasn't the Master (the meddling monk). Do you mean specifically that the villain was human rather than a Time Lord?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes, I think it was the inclusion of a *human* time traveler that really seemed out of place.

Answer (score 2):

All evidence points to this being changed during the later stages of pre-production.

According to the article in *Doctor Who Magazine* issue 475, the change was the request of producer Philip Hinchcliffe, as he "didn't want to have the Master revealed as the secret villain twice in the same season".

Scenario and script-writing is usually the first stage of pre-production, and it appears that an original draft of the script featuring the Master was given to the producer, who then ordered it to be re-written, before they reached the production stage. This is backed up by the fact that several elements in the finished shooting script were clearly written to be the Master, and then altered. The 'time cabinet' is an obvious substitute for his TARDIS, but the most telling element is that he mentions regeneration, saying that "*she* [Leela] *will be the first morsel to feed my regeneration*".